# Notification.php for Windows Azure notification hub API using PHP

Tags: azure-notificationhub

I want to send the notification, using windows azure notification hub api in PHP.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow, it is usually recommended that you demonstrate your attempts so far and explain why they don't work. Please see the [help/on-topic] for more info

Answer (score 2):

You have to interface directly with REST (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn495827.aspx).

The code you will have to write is basically this one:

```
class Notification {
    public $format;
    public $payload;

    # array with keynames for headers
    # Note: Some headers are mandatory: Windows: X-WNS-Type, WindowsPhone: X-NotificationType
    # Note: For Apple you can set Expiry with header: ServiceBusNotification-ApnsExpiry in W3C DTF, YYYY-MM-DDThh:mmTZD (for example, 1997-07-16T19:20+01:00).
    public $headers;

    function __construct($format, $payload) {
        if (!in_array($format, ["template", "apple", "windows", "gcm", "windowsphone"])) {
            throw new Exception('Invalid format: ' . $format);
        }

        $this->format = $format;
        $this->payload = $payload;
    }
}

class NotificationHub {

    const API_VERSION = "?api-version=2013-10";

    private $endpoint;
    private $hubPath;
    private $sasKeyName;
    private $sasKeyValue;

    function __construct($connectionString, $hubPath) {
        $this->hubPath = $hubPath;

        $this->parseConnectionString($connectionString);
    }

    private function parseConnectionString($connectionString) {
        $parts = explode(";", $connectionString);
        if (sizeof($parts) != 3) {
            throw new Exception("Error parsing connection string: " . $connectionString);
        }

        foreach ($parts as $part) {
            if (strpos($part, "Endpoint") === 0) {
                $this->endpoint = "https" . substr($part, 11);
            } else if (strpos($part, "SharedAccessKeyName") === 0) {
                $this->sasKeyName = substr($part, 20);
            } else if (strpos($part, "SharedAccessKey") === 0) {
                $this->sasKeyValue = substr($part, 16);
            }
        }
    }

    private function generateSasToken($uri) {
        $targetUri = strtolower(rawurlencode(strtolower($uri)));

        $expires = time();
        $expiresInMins = 60;
        $expires = $expires + $expiresInMins * 60;
        $toSign = $targetUri . "\n" . $expires;

        $signature = rawurlencode(base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $toSign, $this->sasKeyValue, TRUE)));

        $token = "SharedAccessSignature sr=" . $targetUri . "&sig="
                    . $signature . "&se=" . $expires . "&skn=" . $this->sasKeyName;

        return $token;
    }

    public function broadcastNotification($notification) {
        $this->sendNotification($notification, "");
    }

    public function sendNotification($notification, $tagsOrTagExpression) {
        if (is_array($tagsOrTagExpression)) {
            $tagExpression = implode(" || ", $tagsOrTagExpression);
        } else {
            $tagExpression = $tagsOrTagExpression;
        }

        # build uri
        $uri = $this->endpoint . $this->hubPath . "/messages" . NotificationHub::API_VERSION;
        $ch = curl_init($uri);

        if (in_array($notification->format, ["template", "apple", "gcm"])) {
            $contentType = "application/json";
        } else {
            $contentType = "application/xml";
        }

        $token = $this->generateSasToken($uri);

        $headers = [
            'Authorization: '.$token,
            'Content-Type: '.$contentType,
            'ServiceBusNotification-Format: '.$notification->format
        ];

        if ("" !== $tagExpression) {
            $headers[] = 'ServiceBusNotification-Tags: '.$tagExpression;
        }

        # add headers for other platforms
        if (is_array($notification->headers)) {
            $headers = array_merge($headers, $notification->headers);
        }

        curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
            CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $notification->payload
        ));

        // Send the request
        $response = curl_exec($ch);

        // Check for errors
        if($response === FALSE){
            throw new Exception(curl_error($ch));
        }

        $info = curl_getinfo($ch);

        if ($info['http_code'] <> 201) {
            throw new Exception('Error sending notificaiton: '. $info['http_code'] . ' msg: ' . $response);
        }
    } 
}
```

And use it this way: initialize your Notification Hubs client (substitute the connection string and hub name as instructed in the [Get started tutorial](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-ios-get-started/)):

```
$hub = new NotificationHub("connection string", "hubname");
```

Then add the send code depending on your target mobile platform.

#### Windows Store and Windows Phone 8.1 (non-Silverlight)

```
$toast = '<toast><visual><binding template="ToastText01"><text id="1">Hello from PHP!</text></binding></visual></toast>';
$notification = new Notification("windows", $toast);
$notification->headers[] = 'X-WNS-Type: wns/toast';
$hub->sendNotification($notification);
```

#### iOS

```
$alert = '{"aps":{"alert":"Hello from PHP!"}}';
$notification = new Notification("apple", $alert);
$hub->sendNotification($notification);
```

#### Android

```
$message = '{"data":{"msg":"Hello from PHP!"}}';
$notification = new Notification("gcm", $message);
$hub->sendNotification($notification);
```

#### Windows Phone 8.0 and 8.1 Silverlight

```
$toast = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' .
            '<wp:Notification xmlns:wp="WPNotification">' .
               '<wp:Toast>' .
                    '<wp:Text1>Hello from PHP!</wp:Text1>' .
               '</wp:Toast> ' .
            '</wp:Notification>';
$notification = new Notification("mpns", $toast);
$notification->headers[] = 'X-WindowsPhone-Target : toast';
$notification->headers[] = 'X-NotificationClass : 2';
$hub->sendNotification($notification);
```

#### Kindle Fire

```
$message = '{"data":{"msg":"Hello from PHP!"}}';
$notification = new Notification("adm", $message);
$hub->sendNotification($notification);
```

For registration management you have to follow the content formats shown in the MSDN topic linked above, and probably do some nasty xml parsing... Be warned that element order is important and things will not work if the element are out of order.